# How to convert Mono<PojoResponseObject> to a Mono<ResponseEntity> using webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have the following webclient call

```
public Mono<String> sendFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    Mono<Response> response = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI("someurl"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);

    // Need to implement additional logic here to convert the Mono<Response> into Mono<RequestID>

}

public class Response {

    private RequestID requestID;

}

public class RequestID {

    private String requestID;

}
```

The call to the API gets returned back into a JSON Response POJO object however I am only interested in the requestID which lives in my RequestID POJO so I want to convert my Mono < Response > into a Mono< RequestId > but not sure how to do that?

So for my controller I basically want something similar to this:

```
@PostMapping("/request")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> sendRequest(@RequestPart(value = "file") final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        Mono<RequestID> request =  service.sendFile(multipartFile);
        Response2<String> response = new Response<>(request.getRequestID, true, "SUCCESS"); // Response2 is just a POJO with three fields
        return new Mono<ResponseEntity<>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: [`Mono#map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to transform the emitted data by Mono into another Mono

> Transform the item emitted by this Mono by applying a synchronous function to it.

so the logic will be

```
public Mono<String> sendFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
Mono<Response> response = webClient.post()
            .uri(new URI("someurl"))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class)
            .map(data->data.getRequestID().getRequestID());

  return response;

}
```

In the controller also use `map` method for data transformation into `Mono<ResponseEntity>`

```
@PostMapping("/request")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> sendRequest(@RequestPart(value = "file") final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    Mono<RequestID> request =  service.sendFile(multipartFile);
    
    return request.map(id->ResponseEntity.body(new Response<>(id, true, "SUCCESS")).status(HttpStatus.CREATED)));
}
```